# GLuint not being recognised

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, textures, glut

I am creating a 3D application in OpenGL, and in order to display textures on the models that I'm reading in, I'm using GLuint. However, I am getting the visual studio error C4430 missing type, and a handful of others related to the issue.

The glut files are included and were working fine before this was put in. Is it that GLuint is outdated, or something else?

Edit:
The code that has changed is:

Object constructor before

```
Object::Object(string shapeFileName, string texFileName){
    readFile(shapeFileName);
    loadTexture(texFileName);
}
```

Object constructor afterwards

```
Object::Object(string shapeFileName, string texFileName){
    readFile(shapeFileName);

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    loadTexture(texFileName);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, 1024, 512, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_array);

    free(image_array);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, 1024, 512, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_array);
}
```

Along with the line `GLuint texture;` added in the header file, which is the only bit that is throwing an error.

Comment: Can you show some code, please? Best would be a before-after comparison, i.e. a working code and one which fails to compile, as you say it was "working fine before this was put in"...

Comment: @leemes: If someone hasn't provided enough information to answer the question, please vote to close.

Comment: It is just that issue. I just added in an uninitialised variable `GLuint texture;`

Comment: We need more context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you include the OpenGL header in the header you're declaring the variable in? `GLuint` is defined in `gl.h` so you must include that.

On all operating systems *except* MacOS X it's

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
```

on MacOS X it is

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
```

Comment: @Yann4: Define "right places". The compilation error you quoted clearly tells it's not included at all the important places.

Comment: It is defined in the header file, the .cpp file that the header file refers to and the main file, all with include guards

Answer (score 4):

I think you should be using glew and include:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
```

rather than:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
```

Answer (score -1):

For iOS you need to link OpenGLES.framework to your target and import header in your code:

```
#import <OpenGLES/gltypes.h>
```